# cropped image and layer it at some position in a second canvas-imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, crop

I would like to crop image and flatten it over a second canvas.
for instance, my image1 crop would be=>

```
 -crop 20x800+450+0
```

and I would like to put it at the position of my second image.

```
-page 0+0
```

this just doesn't work=>

```
convert -page 0+0 image1.jpg -crop 20x800+450+0 -layers flatten image2.jpg
```

how could I do this ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I find your question very hard to understand, but let's assume you have this:

```
# a canvas
convert -size 1200x1200 xc:gray canvas.png
```

[image]

and an image:

```
convert -size 1000x1000 gradient:red-blue image1.png
```

[image]

Then I am guessing you want this:

```
convert canvas.png \( image1.png -crop 20x800+450+0 \) -composite  result.png
```

[image]

That works because the default `-gravity` is `NorthWest`, if you wanted it elsewhere you can do things like this:

```
convert canvas.png \( image1.png -crop 20x800+450+0 \) -gravity east -composite  result.png
```

[image]

Or this, with an up-down offset from the South side:

```
convert canvas.png \( image1.png -crop 20x800+450+0 \) -gravity south -geometry +0+50 -composite  result.png
```

[image]

Or with a left-right offset from the West side:

```
convert canvas.png \( image1.png -crop 20x800+450+0 \) -gravity west -geometry +100 -composite  result.png
```

[image]

Or maybe you want to rotate the extracted crop before overlaying it:

```
convert canvas.png \( image1.png -crop 20x800+450+0 -rotate 90 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+20 -composite  result.png
```

[image]

Or maybe you were trying to do it this way:

```
convert canvas.png -respect-parentheses \( -page +300+50 image1.png -crop 20x800+450+0 \) -layers flatten result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely brillant !!